# Probability that sum of independent random (non iid) variables exceeds the variance infinitely often

Tags: central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be independent random variables, with $\Pr[X_i=\sigma_i]=\Pr[X_i=-\sigma_i]=1/2$ ($\sigma_i\geq 0$).  Suppose that:

(a) There is an upper bound $B$ such that $\sigma_i\leq B$ for all $i$.

(b) There is a lower bound $A>0$ such that $\sigma_i>A$ for infinitely many $i$'s.

Set $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $(\Sigma_n)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2$. Then, $(\Sigma_n)^2=Var(S_n)$ (the variance). By assumption (b) $\Sigma_n$ goes to $\infty$.

Consider $0<\alpha < 1$.  I want to understand the probability of the event $S_n \geq \alpha (\Sigma_n)^2$.

Since $\Sigma_n \rightarrow \infty$ the central limit theorem holds and we have that

$\Pr[S_n \geq \alpha (\Sigma_n)^2]=\Pr[\frac{S_n}{\Sigma_n} \geq \alpha \Sigma_n] \approx
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\alpha\Sigma_n}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}dx $,

which goes to $0$ since $\Sigma_n$ goes to $\infty$.  So, the probability of the event with which I am concerned goes to $0$.

Now the question is about the probability that the event happens infinitely often.  Specifically, I would like to have that

$\Pr[S_n \geq \alpha (\Sigma_n)^2\; \mbox{infinitely often}]=0 .
$

Is this true? For applying the Borel Cantelli lemma I would need to estimate the sum of the integrals, which I do not know how to do.  Any ideas? counter example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a proof:

Denote $n(i)$ such that $\Sigma_{n(i)}=i$.

Denote by $A_k$ the event that there exists $i\in \{n(k^2),\ldots,n((k+1)^2\}$ for which $S_i\geq \alpha(\Sigma_i)^2$.   We shall prove that there exists $c$ for which $\Pr[A_k]\leq c/k^2$ for all $k$.

Set $\beta=\alpha/2$. Then, for any $k$, considering $n(k^2)$,

$\Pr[ S_{n(k^2)} > \beta\cdot(\Sigma_{n(k^2)})^2 ] \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\beta\cdot k^2}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}dx < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot \frac{1}{\beta\cdot k^2} =\frac{c_1}{k^2},
$

for the appropriate $c_1$.

Now consider the random variables $X_i$ for $i=n(k^2)+1,\ldots,n((k+1)^2)$.  Set $D_{j}=\sum_{i=n(k^2)+1}^{j} X_i$.  Then

$Var(D_{n((k+1)^2)})=(\Sigma_{n((k+1)^2)})^2-(\Sigma_{n(k^2)})^2=(k+1)^4-k^4 = O(k^3).
$

So, by the Kolmogorov inequality

$
\Pr[\sup_{n(k^2)<j\leq n((k+1)^2)} D_j \geq \beta(k+1)^4 ] \leq \frac{Var(D_{n((k_1)^2)})}{(\beta(k+1)^4)^{2}}= \frac{O(k^3)}{\beta^2(k+1)^8} \ll \frac{c_2}{k^2}
$

for some constant $c_2$.

So, for any $k$,

$
\Pr[A_k]\leq \Pr[\sup_{n(k^2)<j\leq n((k+1)^2)} S_{j} \geq \alpha (k+1)^4 ]\leq 
$

$
\Pr[S_{n(k^2)}>\beta (k+1)^4]+Pr[\sup_{n(k^2)<j\leq n((k+1)^2)} D_{j} \geq \beta(k+1)^4 ]\leq 
$

$
 \leq \frac{c_1+c_2}{k^2} .
$

So,

$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Pr[A_k] < \infty ,
$
and the result follows by the Borel Cantelli lemma.

Is this right?